# JSON_MODIFY all values without looping

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

See sample below. How would I use `JSON_MODIFY` or other way to modify all the "disc" values to "100" without having to update each array item in a loop?

```
create table #temp_data (json_text nvarchar(max))
insert into #temp_data select 
'
   "curr":"USD",
   "items":[
      {
         "line":1,
         "disc":10,
      },
      {
         "line":2,
         "disc":11
      },
      {
         "line":3,
         "disc":12,
      }
   ]
}'
select * from #temp_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't actually need to parse the rest of the JSON, we only need the `$.items` part. So we can `APPLY` that property with `OPENJSON`, then reassemble it with `JSON_MODIFY`:

```sql
UPDATE t
SET json_text = JSON_MODIFY(t.json_text, '$.items', v.items)
FROM temp_data t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT line, disc = 100
    FROM OPENJSON(t.json_text, '$.items') WITH (line int) AS items
    FOR JSON PATH
  ) v(items);
```

In the `WITH` block, we need to add all properties we are not modifying, then in the inner `SELECT` we add any columns we want to change.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the traditional SQL DML UPDATE to replace the json_text with a new piece of JSON derived from the existing.  Something like this

JSON_MODIFY could be added if that's a requirement.

```
drop table if exists #temp_data;
go
create table #temp_data (json_text nvarchar(max));

insert into #temp_data(json_text) values( 
N'{
   "curr":"USD",
   "items":[
      {
         "line":1,
         "disc":10
      },
      {
         "line":2,
         "disc":11
      },
      {
         "line":3,
         "disc":12
      }
   ]
}');

update #temp_data
set json_text=( select json_value(d.json_text, N'strict $.curr') curr, 
                       (select j2.line, j2.disc+100 as disc
                        from #temp_data td
                        cross apply openjson(td.json_text) 
                                     with(curr       nvarchar(20),
                                          items      nvarchar(max) as json) j1
                     cross apply openjson(j1.items)
                                     with(line       int,
                                          disc       int) j2
                        for json path) items
                from #temp_data d
                for json path, without_array_wrapper);

select * from #temp_data;
```

```
{
  "curr": "USD",
  "items": [
    {
      "line": 1,
      "disc": 210
    },
    {
      "line": 2,
      "disc": 211
    },
    {
      "line": 3,
      "disc": 212
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use a wildcard in a `JSON_MODIFY()` call, so one possible approach are the following steps:

- Parse the `$.items` array from the stored JSON using `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema including the `line` key.
- Set the new value for the `disc` key for each item of this array.
- Generate the JSON again using `FOR JSON PATH`.
- Update the table with `JSON_MODIFY()`.

Table:

```
create table #temp_data (json_text nvarchar(max))
insert into #temp_data (json_text)
VALUES (N'
{
   "curr":"USD",
   "items":[
      {"line":1, "disc":10},
      {"line":2, "disc":11},
      {"line":3, "disc":12}
   ]
}')
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #temp_data
SET json_text = JSON_MODIFY(
   json_text,
   '$.items',
   (
   SELECT line, 100 AS disc
   FROM OPENJSON(json_text, '$.items') WITH (line int '$.line')
   FOR JSON PATH
   )
)
```

Result:

```
json_text
{
   "curr":"USD",
   "items":[{"line":1,"disc":100},{"line":2,"disc":100},{"line":3,"disc":100}]
}
```